# Application crashing on startup due to click listener?

Tags: android

This code which compiles fine seems to crash my application at startup

```
private OnClickListener teamlisten = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}; 
 //this is in OnCreate
Button teambtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.teams);
teambtn.setOnClickListener(teamlisten);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: What is the exception? Look into the LogCat view to find out. I guess you might have a null pointer on getListView() or findViewById() (or both).

Comment: oh, I just love people that thinks compile fine == code is correct.

Comment: ^ Yeah except he didn't say "compiles = correct" hence, the asking of the question. Maybe you should keep snide remarks to yourself. As for the question, it seems `getListView()` would cause a problem, but without more information we can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have some conflicting issues here. You say you use

```
Button teambtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.teams);
```

but later you also have

```
getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Those 2 things don't make sense together. Either you have a listactivity, in which you haven't called setContentView and thuse you can't call `findViewById()`. Or you're overriding a regular activity with your own listview, but then you don't have the `getListView()` method.

Do you understand now why we need more code to help you? You didn't even post a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.teams)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
   });
```

Maybe this will not help but who knows.
if it doesn't work, give more details ! :)